# TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, mocha.js, chai

I don't get while running the application, it only happens when i run test. Basically I have written snapshot test for now.

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined  at
>   Papertype.render (src/components/layoutcomponents/papertype.js:50:23)

Here is code in papertype.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import common from '../../jsons/common.json';

import catalogSpecs from '../../jsons/infiniti.json';


class Papertype extends Component {

    constructor(props) {

        super(props);

        this.state = {

            paperType: "Regular",

            regularPaper : true,

            heavyPaper : false
        }
    }
    changePaperTypeLayoutParams(event){

        let nameSelection = event.target.value;

        let lalala = catalogSpecs.commonProps.paperType.paperTypeDefinitionDTOs

        let paperTypebinding = lalala[nameSelection].absolutelayflat;

        let paperLaminationVisibility = lalala[nameSelection].paperLamination;

        this.setState({

            paperType: nameSelection

        });

        if(nameSelection.indexOf("Regular")>-1 || 

nameSelection.indexOf("Metallic")>-1){

            this.setState({

                regularPaper : true,

                heavyPaper : false
            });
            this.props.setRegularOrHeavy(true,false,paperTypebinding,paperLaminationVisibility);

        }else{

            this.setState({

                heavyPaper : true,

                regularPaper : false

            });
            this.props.setRegularOrHeavy(false,true,paperTypebinding,paperLaminationVisibility);
        }



    }
    render() {

        let validLayoutPaperType=this.props.validLayoutPaperType;

        let paperTypeOptions = [];
        let paperTypeOpts = common.paperTypeOpts;
        for(let i=0;i<validLayoutPaperType.length;i++){
            let paper = paperTypeOpts[validLayoutPaperType[i]]
            paperTypeOptions.push(<option label={paper} value={paper} key={i}>{paper}</option>)
        }
        return(
            <div className="layout-item">
                <label>Paper Type</label>
                <div className="custom-select">
                    <select className="form-control" onChange={this.changePaperTypeLayoutParams.bind(this)}>
                        {paperTypeOptions}
                    </select>
                    <i className="icon icon-angle-down"></i>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
export default Papertype;
```

Comment: Try `console.log(this.props.validLayoutPaperType)` in render.

Answer (score 0):

The error is referring to you trying to obtain a length of an undefined variable.

It appears that the `props` object does not have `validLayoutPaperType` defined.  As a result, your local `validLayoutPaperType` (in `render`) is undefined.

Comment: console.log(this.props.validLayoutPaperType) gives an array
[ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 ]

Comment: Inside the render method, or outside the render method?  That is where are you dumping that properly to the console?

Comment: I printed inside render method ..
  render() {
        let validLayoutPaperType=this.props.validLayoutPaperType;

        console.log(this.props.validLayoutPaperType);
        
        let paperTypeOptions = [];
        
       let paperTypeOpts = common.paperTypeOpts;
       
      for(let i=0;i<validLayoutPaperType.length;i++){
     
       let paper = paperTypeOpts[validLayoutPaperType[i]]

            paperTypeOptions.push(<option label={paper} value={paper} 

key={i}>{paper}</option>)

        }

Comment: You are dumping `this.props.validLayoutPaperType`.  What is the value of the local `validLayoutPaperType`.  That is, if you add a breakpoint on the console.log statement, then what is the value of `validLayoutPaperType` and `validLayoutPaperType.length` (before the start of the loop).